# How can I get four separate git repository(with multiple branch) in one jenkins pipeline(using groovy ) or in one workspace?

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, repository, jenkins-pipeline

I have four different projects(or repositories). I would like to create a pipeline that pull code from different repositories(selection of branch from particular repo is also present). After pulling code i would like to run docker images of these projects

```
pipeline {
  agent any
   parameters {
    gitParameter branchFilter: 'origin.*/(.*)', defaultValue:'master',name: 'BRANCH_CORE', type: 'PT_BRANCH'

    gitParameter branchFilter: 'origin.*/(.*)', defaultValue: 'master', name: 'BRANCH_STATS', type: 'PT_BRANCH'

    gitParameter branchFilter: 'origin.*/(.*)', defaultValue: 'master', name: 'BRANCH_NOTIFICATION', type: 'PT_BRANCH'

     gitParameter branchFilter: 'origin.*/(.*)', defaultValue: 'master', name: 'BRANCH_SESSION', type: 'PT_BRANCH'

  }
  stages
  {
      stage('SCM Checkout Core') 
    {
      steps 
      {
        git branch: "${params.BRANCH_CORE}", url: 'URL of core repo'
      }
    }
      stage('SCM Checkout Stats') 
    {
      steps 
      {
        git branch: "${params.BRANCH_STATS}", url: 'URL of stats repo'
      }
    }
    stage('SCM Checkout Notification') 
    {
      steps {
        git branch: "${params.BRANCH_NOTIFICATION}",url: 'URL of notification repo '
      }
    }
      stage('SCM Checkout Session') {
       steps {
         git branch: "${params.BRANCH_SESSION}",url: 'URL of session repo '
       }
     }
  }
}
```

I am expecting a directory where i can get multiple project directory( according to our selected code branch )